# How to add a fixed number to the integer part of a filename?

Tags: python, file-rename

Using Python, I need to add 100 to the integer part of some filenames to rename the files. The files look like this: `0000000_6dee7e249cf3.log`  where  `6dee7e249cf3` is a random number. At the end I should have:

```
0000000_6dee7e249cf3.log should change to 0000100_6dee7e249cf3.log
0000001_12b2bb88d493.log should change to 0000101_12b2bb88d493.log
etc, etc…
```

I can print the initial files using:

```
initial: glob('{0:07d}_*[a-z]*'.format(NUM))
```

but the final files returns an empty list:

```
final: glob('{0:07d}_*[a-z]*'.format(NUM+100))
```

Moreover, I cannot not rename initial to final using os.rename because it can not read the list created using the globe function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've included your regex search.  It looks like glob doesn't handle regex, but re does

```
import os
import re
#for all files in current directory
for f in os.listdir('./'):
    #if the first 7 chars are numbers
    if re.search('[0-9]{7}',f):
        lead_int = int(f.split('_')[0])
        #if the leading integer is less than 100
        if lead_int < 100:
            # rename this file with leading integer + 100
            os.rename(f,'%07d_%s'%(lead_int + 100,f.split('_')[-1]))
```

Comment: Thank you EMiller, works perfectly! Only a typo at the last line: fl.split should be f.split.

Comment: I prefer to use str.format instead of % so I would write the last line as:  'os.rename(f,'{0:07d}{1}{2}'.format(lead_int + 100,'_' , f.split('_')[-1]))' which gives the same result as 'os.rename(f,'%07d_%s'%(lead_int + 100,fl.split('_')[-1]))' suggested by EMiller –

Answer (score 0):

Split the file name value using '_' separator and use those two values to reconstruct your file name.

```
s = name.split('_')
n2 = str(int(s[0]) + 100)
new_name = s[0][:len(s[0]) - len(n2)] + n2 + '_' + s[1]
```